# Error casting datatypes in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, decimal, to-char

I'm hitting error while running this statement in sql server..

```
DECIMAL(TO_CHAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP -1 DAYS,'yyyymmdd')8,0)
```

Comment: Is this MS sql server? What specific error are you getting?

Comment: It throws error as SQL##f - SqlState: 37000, ErrorCode: 156, ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT'. I tried with CAST/CONVERT also but not getting the result

Comment: I want to add previous day records. Yes it's Sql server only. This statement works fine in DB2 though.

Comment: the sql languages between db2 and ms sql server are not exactly the same. Can you tell me what you expect this specific statement to do?

Comment: I want my query to go back one day to the system date and extract the data. The Date field should be in YYYYMMDD format only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `MSSQL` it's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you forgot the underscore.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `TO_CHAR`...  But that's not the only problem with this syntax. You're mixing together a lot of different RDBMS's here...

I'm just guessing what you're trying to do but this seems to be what you're looking for:

```
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DD, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DECIMAL(8, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. That works. I was trying my query to go back one day and extract the data. Right now I see no data for the previous day though in DB. Thanks again